# Multiple datatables on one page not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I created as simple of an example as I possibly could of what I am trying to do - that is dynamically generate a few datatables in my page.

here is [a link to jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6rx6bbL1/9/), but I also want to post the core code here for clarity:

```
<div id="tables"></div>

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var data = [{"MessageId":"e5368264-dd06-403b-85cd-f82c1a0bd685","MessageNumber":"M54740"},{"MessageId":"f6130eb7-2980-4e19-8f4b-d16473add97b","MessageNumber":"M54584"}];

    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        var tableCode = '<table id="table_' + i + '" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>';  
        $('#tables').html($('#tables').html() + tableCode);

        $('#table_' + i).DataTable
        ({
            data: data,
            columns:
            [
                { data: 'MessageId', title: 'Id', "searchable": true },
                { data: 'MessageNumber', title: 'Number', "searchable": true }
            ]
        });
    }
} );
```

What I am doing here is I dynamically generate a few datatables. Unfortunately I come to realization that the basic **events (like search and sorting) only get applied to the last added one**.

Correct me if I am wrong, but this reminds of the problems with jquery events where, when you want to make everything work every time (I especially mean the html elements generated AFTER the event was assigned), you have to write code like:

```
$(document).on('change', '.search-select', function (event){ ... });
```

rather than

```
$('.search-select').change(function (event){ ... });
```

which leads to the question: am I doomed and the datatables won't simply work and thus I can only be saved by editing a few lines in the source code (which would take a tremendous amount of time to understand a library not written by myself) or... are there simpler solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use `.append()` instead of `.html()` as `$('#tables').html($('#tables').html() + tableCode);` will remove events from earlier appended elements.

For example, `document.body.innerHTML += '<br>'` ==> `document.body.innerHTML = (document.body.innerHTML + '<br>');` will destroy and re-create the content again.

Use `$('#tables').append(tableCode);` instead of  `$('#tables').html($('#tables').html() + tableCode);`

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/6rx6bbL1/10/)

Comment: Oh wow! Silly me :( You saved me so much of a headache! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Trigger datatable once in the code using the attribute selector to select al the divs

Add the html to a string and then append it to the table

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
        var data = [{"MessageId":"e5368264-dd06-403b-85cd-f82c1a0bd685","MessageNumber":"M54740"},{"MessageId":"f6130eb7-2980-4e19-8f4b-d16473add97b","MessageNumber":"M54584"}];


        var tableCode ='';
        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        tableCode += '<table id="table_' + i + '" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>';  


    }
     $('#tables').html(tableCode);
        $('table[id^="table_"]').DataTable
        ({
            data: data,
            columns:
            [
                    { data: 'MessageId', title: 'Id', "searchable": true },
                    { data: 'MessageNumber', title: 'Number', "searchable": true }
            ]
        });
} );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9jnsvam6/1/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have  and  tags in the table or you will get - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined